# Pipelines with Strapi Headless CMS

Tags: deployment, pipeline, headless, bitbucket-pipelines, strapi

I have build local a website, based on VueJs, NuxtJs and Strapi. My Server (on one.com) can not handle nodeJs. So i want to build my page as a static site. My plan is to run a pipline, which start my node server, so my application can get the data out of strapi, build the pages and next upload it automatically on my server as HTML, CSS and JS.

At the moment my Pipeline starts the server, but do not move on.

```
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Start Strapi Node Server
          deployment: live
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - cd server
            - npm ci
            - npm run start

      - step:
          name: Frontend Build Process
          caches:
            - node
          script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
            - npm ci
            - npm run build
          artifacts:
            - dist/**
```

Comment: Found out that i can run nuxt with gernate ---> But this still does not fix my problem with the piplines. On generate the strapi serve must run

Comment: Where do you think is your Database hosted in this example?